# Equivalence of two exponentially equaled matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

Let $O\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$; if $A,B\in (\exp)^{-1}(O)$. Could we prove that there exists an unitary matrix, such that
$$
A=UBU^\dagger + \Lambda,
$$
in which, $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are integer multiple of $2\pi$.

(thanks to @loup blanc, I have rephrased the question.)

Comment: I don't know how you are defining the logarithm, but shouldn't $A=B$ simply imply $\log A=\log B$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, It is matrix logarithm. The usual equality does not apply here. And the matrix logarithm is defined as $\exp\{\log A}\}=A$

Comment: That doesn't tell me how you are defining the logarithm, and it doesn't answer my question. But anyway what you've written is clearly false for $N=1$.

Comment: OK, I see you've extended your comment. But, still....

Comment: @GerryMyerson, here is the wikipedia definition of matrix logarithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: If you look at the example there having to do with rotations of the plane, doesn't it show your formula is wrong? And the case $N=1$?

Comment: A matrix $A$ may have many logarithms. But the moment you write $\log A$, you have chosen a _specific one_, and that choice will also, implicitly, stay the same if you rename $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Hate to keep raising the same question, but you seem to be avoiding it. In your edited formulation, what happens when $N=1$?

Answer (score 4):

A correctly written question is (for example):

Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$; if $U,V\in (\exp)^{-1}(A)$, is it true that $U-V$ is a diagonal matrix ?

The answer is no, as the following example shows:

$A=I_2,U=0_2,V=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2\pi\\2\pi&0\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT. I think you do not understand how the exponential works.

Proposition. Assume that $e^U=e^V$ and that $spectrum(U)$ is $2i\pi$ congruence-free (for every $s,t\in spectrum(U),s-t\notin 2i\pi \mathbb{Z}^*$). Then, there are $P\in GL_n$ and  $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix whose entries are integer multiple of $2iπ$ s.t. $U-V=P\Lambda P^{-1}$.

Proof. From a theorem by Hille, we deduce that $UV=VU$; then $e^{U-V}=I_n$; therefore $U-V$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are in $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Remark. Proposition applies to my above example. Of course, if $U$ is not $2i\pi$ C.F., then the result is no more valid.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the ambiguity in the phrase, I have restated the question. What I want to prove is that can we prove there exists an unitary matrix that transforms U to V up to a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I don't see why U and V should commute. Could you please explain a little about the Hille Theorem? Cause I can only find the Hille-Yoshida theorem, which seems irrelevant to this proposition.

Comment: The reference is here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01350286

Comment: thanks a lot! I will look it up.